# titanium mobile:onload function called issue in json parsing

Tags: titanium-mobile

Hello friends,

I am developing an app in Titanium Studio sdk 1.8.1 using Google Place API to display category atm list & address in tableview so I use json parsing using this [link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&name=ATM&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDALrXHC4uMtfSrpCg6NHxqPhsLccLYPZE) **but loader.onload function of getData method is not called immediately after send function of getData method in json parsing  so its called after getDetailsData() function** and also can't display address in tableview so please give me idea how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

```
var lat ,lon ,radius , name , sensor , key , reference, address;
lat = '-33.8670522';//'23.042067';
lon = '151.1957362';//'72.530835';//
radius = '500';
name = title;
sensor = 'false';
key = 'AIzaSyDALrXHC4uMtfSrpCg6NHxqPhsLccLYPZE';

var rowData = [];

// getCategoryData using Google Place API
function getData()
{
    var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";    
    url = url + "location=" + lat + ',' + lon;
    url = url + "&radius=" + radius;
    url = url + "&name=" + name;
    url = url + "&sensor=" + sensor;
    url = url + "&key=" + key;

    Ti.API.info(url);
    // Sets the HTTP request method, and the URL to get data from
    loader.open("GET",url);
    // Create our HTTP Client and name it "loader"
    // Runs the function when the data is ready for us to process
    loader.onload = function() 
    {
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.log(obj);    
        var results = obj.results;
        Ti.API.log(results);
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        {
            var name = obj.results[i].name; 
            reference = obj.results[i].reference;
            Ti.API.log('Refernce:'+reference);

                     getDetailsData();

            // Create a row and set its height to auto
            var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({height:'auto'});

            // Create the view that will contain the text and avatar
            var post_view = Titanium.UI.createView({
                height:'auto', 
                layout:'vertical',
                top:5,
                right:5,
                bottom:5,
                left:5
            });
                // Create the label to hold the tweet message
            var nameLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                //text:name,
                left:30,
                top:0,
                bottom:2,
                height:'auto',
                width:236,
                textAlign:'left',
                font:{fontSize:14}
            });

            // Create the label to hold the tweet message
            var addressLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                text:'Address',
                left:30,
                top:0,
                bottom:2,
                height:'auto',
                width:236,
                textAlign:'left',
                font:{fontSize:14}
            });

            nameLabel.text = name;
            //addressLabel.text = placeAddress;

            post_view.add(nameLabel);
            post_view.add(addressLabel);

            // Add the post view to the row
            row.add(post_view);
            // Give each row a class name
            //row.className = "item"+i;
            // Add row to the rowData array
            rowData[i] = row;
            //rowData.push(row);
        }

        //tableView.setData(rowData);
        // Create the table view and set its data source to "rowData" array
        var tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({data:rowData});
        //Add the table view to the window
        showWin.add(tableView);
    };
    //-- Network error
    loader.onerror = function(e)
    {
        Ti.API.info('Network error: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
    };


    // Send the HTTP request
    loader.send();
}




function getDetailsData () 
{
    var loader1 = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    Ti.API.log('getDetailsData');
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";    
    url = url + "reference=" + reference;
    url = url + "&sensor=" + sensor;
    url = url + "&key=" + key;
    Ti.API.info(url);

    // Sets the HTTP request method, and the URL to get data from
    loader1.open("GET",url);

    // Runs the function when the data is ready for us to process
    loader1.onload = function() 
    {
        var detailsObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.log(detailsObj); 

        address = detailsObj.result.formatted_address;
        Ti.API.log('Address:'+address);

        phoneno = detailsObj.result.formatted_phone_number;
        Ti.API.log('Phone No:'+phoneno);
    };

    //-- Network error
    loader1.onerror = function(event)
    {
        Ti.API.info('Network error: ' + JSON.stringify(event));
    };

    // Send the HTTP request
    loader1.send();

    return address;
}

getData();
```

[image]     [image]

Comment: Where do you want to display the address? In second or first screen?

Comment: in second screen below each atm name

Comment: Can you just explain the flow of two http requests? Why are you using two requests?

Comment: please read my update for loop code and I called getDetailsData() method in for loop and want to display each atm address in below atm name but not called onload function of getDetailsData() so please give me any idea how to solve it

Comment: I don't think that another http call from onload will work. Try to do this: Push all the data from first http request into an array. After that run a for loop on that array and in that loop make a request for address, and in this loop make your rows data as well.

Comment: I already take an array[results] and run for loop but solve my issue so please see my code and give me idea for my solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav)

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont't use the return in the second http request.
Pass the label object in the function like:

> getDetailsData(addressLabel);

and set the text inside **loader1.onload** like this:

> address = detailsObj.result.formatted_address;
>
> addressLabel.text = address;

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav